# Visual Studio- accessing Smart Tags without help from Design View

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

I mainly do C# ASP.NET projects in VS2010.  Once you've put masterpages and other things in place, I find the design view pretty much goes grey and elements can't be selected.  This isn't so bad except that sometimes you need to access the little 'smart tags' at the top right of controls to do things.

In particular I'm trying to do this with some telerik controls, though the issue isn't confined to them.

Anyone have a handy tip to access this functionality (or miraculously make design view work!) ?

Thanks!

PS. I read in a few places that Shift-Alt-F10 may help.  I tried putting my cursor in the control's tag and using it, no luck.  Also I clicked the little rectangle below design view to select the control and tried it again- no luck.

Comment: Do you actually think that "the design view goes gray" for every single ASP.NET developer? Instead of looking for hacks, maybe you should ask why your design view is going gray?

Comment: I kind of figured it would, yes.  It happened in VS2008 and has happened on multiple PC's, and I'm not really doing anything enormously complex!  Good thought though, perhaps more testing is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, searching for VS design-time troubleshooting tips in the asp.net forums or MSDN is probably the best start to identify and eliminate the abnormal behavior.